# S3 weird behavior with @ in url

Tags: url, amazon-s3, urlencode

A path like this works in S3:

```
https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/custom.domain/foo@example.ext
```

It also works when it is urlencoded:

```
https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/custom.domain/foo%40example.ext
```

However, with a custom domain it doesn't seem to be working:

```
https://custom.domain/foo@example.ext
```

It returns this error

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>123/123/image.jpg</Key>
<RequestId>E30151C3D86A2BDA</RequestId>
<HostId>
wDvM7EpyNKyaxCuzxyBDoRFb72jrXacqiPcjTwzJ37HHdtR1CM1/df+bEW2Nld44sOcvarcO8j24=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

It works though when it is urlencoded:

```
https://custom.domain/foo%40example.ext
```

Not sure how to get this to work or if its a bug on S3.

**Update**

Weird, it worked after a few minutes, but it doesn't work right away. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Update**

Maybe a clue:

> The reason his happens (and also the reason why it self-resolves), is that when you set up an S3 bucket, there’s a certain time during which the global bucket URL is not available, so AWS redirects to the region-specific URL.
>
> The redirect response that Amazon sends back when you request the global URL doesn’t have CORS headers, so requests will fail until the DNS has propagated.

From http://www.corrspt.com/blog/2016/01/17/uploading-to-amazon-s3-response-for-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-307/

He sums up saying:

> So, I basically only had to wait until Amazon propagated DNS information (took about 2 hours or so, I think). But since it didn’t happen with the development bucket (which I created before I started developing…. so, it makes sense) I got lost there.